# Resetting all fields to initial state in C#.NET WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reset

got a very simple question which I can't seem to find any answer for.

In a standard WinForms application, is there anything I can iterate through in order to find all the relevant input items to reset in a given form?

EG, iterate through all inputs and set TextBox.Text = "", ComboBox.SelectedItem = -1, etc ...

If this was a Web application it'd be easy, I'd just iterate through the Controls collection in the Page. But a Console application doesn't have a Page element, and I've looked at the "this" element, and can't find any way to iterate through the inputs.

Comment: Looks for the `Controls` collection.

Comment: So WInForms or Console application? BTW each Form has Controls collection

Comment: Heh - I'm blind I guess. I swear I didn't see a Controls collection but it's clearly there, so ignore this question I guess :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively loop through the `Controls` collection.

Comment: +1 for "recursively" so you catch any controls embedded in a GroupBox/Panel container.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{                
    ctrl.ResetText();
}
```

[Control ResetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resettext.aspx)