# Update/Reset the WPF grid to its initial state

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing a user interface which collects the data which will be saved into a database. There are text boxes, combo boxes and status bar (including a progress bar) all in the Grid control of window. After a bunch of information is uploaded, I want to reset/update all the controls to their initial states (e.g. textboxes should be empty or progress bar should be hidden until the time it is invoked to be visible etc.) or in the case of the uploading trial of an existing file only status bar should be reset to its initial state.

(this.InitializeComponent() didn't work.)

Similar topics: [Resetting a winform's elements to initialized state (C#/.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337649/resetting-a-winforms-elements-to-initialized-state-c-net)

[Resetting all fields to initial state in C#.NET WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845489/resetting-all-fields-to-initial-state-in-c-net-winforms-application?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM you can set the DataContext of the view with a new instance of the type you are using as a ViewModel.

If you are using code-behind pattern then you can just create a new instance of the UserControl. (If the controls are currently in a Window, move them into a new UserControl and put the UserControl in the Window)